# Apache PIG, JSON Loader

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2

**This is my sample input file:**

```
[{"disknum":36,"disksum":136.401,"disk_rate":1872.0,"disk_lnum": 13}]
[{"disknum":36,"disksum":105.2,"disk_rate":123084.8,"disk_lnum": 13}]
```

I'm trying to parse this JSON data using JsonLoader in PIG,

**Here's is my script:**

```
a = LOAD '/pig/tc.log' using JsonLoader ('disknum:chararray,disksum:chararray,disk_rate:chararray,disk_lnum:chararray');

b = FOREACH a GENERATE disknum,disksum,disk_rate,disk_lnum;

DUMP b;
```

**Expected output:**

> 36,136.401,1872.0,13
>
> 36,105.2,123084.8,13

**Actual Output:**

> ( )

Please help me! what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the [] surrounding the objects in your file.You can either load it to a map and access the fields or use ElephantBird jsonloader.

```
a = LOAD '/pig/tc.log' using JsonLoader(json:map[]);
b = FOREACH a GENERATE flatten(json#'disknum') AS disknum,
                       flatten(json#'disksum') AS disksum,
                       flatten(json#'disk_rate') AS disk_rate,
                       flatten(json#'disk_lnum') AS disk_lnum;      
DUMP b;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time :)
I got an error while trying out ELEPHANTBIRD JSON LOADER, I've posted in below link, could you please help with the error?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064795/apache-pig-elephantbirdjson-loader

Comment: Using Elephantbird JsonLoader I'm able to load the data if the record is in this format:
{"disknum":36,"disksum":136.401,"disk_rate":1872.0,"disk_lnum": 13}

Comment: I have data in the format: `{"disknum":36,"disksum":136.401,"disk_rate":1872.0,"disk_lnum": 13,"tags":["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]}`. Any idea how could this be loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Your input data is JSON array and that's why Pig's JsonLoader fails to read it.
If possible, remove arrays (like below) or see [Load JSON array into Pig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26710438/load-json-array-into-pig). You should be able to figure out the basic principle.

```
{"disknum":36,"disksum":136.401,"disk_rate":1872.0,"disk_lnum": 13}
{"disknum":36,"disksum":105.2,"disk_rate":123084.8,"disk_lnum": 13}
```