# Apache PIG, ELEPHANTBIRDJSON Loader

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2

I'm trying to parse below input (there are 2 records in this input)using Elephantbird json loader

> [{"node_disk_lnum_1":36,"node_disk_xfers_in_rate_sum":136.40000000000001,"node_disk_bytes_in_rate_22":
>   187392.0, "node_disk_lnum_7": 13}]
>
> [{"node_disk_lnum_1": 36, "node_disk_xfers_in_rate_sum":
>   105.2,"node_disk_bytes_in_rate_22": 123084.8, "node_disk_lnum_7":13}]

**Here is my syntax:**

```
register '/home/data/Desktop/elephant-bird-pig-4.1.jar';

a = LOAD '/pig/tc1.log' USING 
com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') as (json:map[]);

b = FOREACH a GENERATE flatten(json#'node_disk_lnum_1') AS 
node_disk_lnum_1,flatten(json#'node_disk_xfers_in_rate_sum') AS 
node_disk_xfers_in_rate_sum,flatten(json#'node_disk_bytes_in_rate_22') AS 
node_disk_bytes_in_rate_22, flatten(json#'node_disk_lnum_7') AS
node_disk_lnum_7;

DESCRIBE b;
```

b describe result:

> b: {node_disk_lnum_1: bytearray,node_disk_xfers_in_rate_sum:
>   bytearray,node_disk_bytes_in_rate_22: bytearray,node_disk_lnum_7:
>   bytearray}

```
c = FOREACH b GENERATE node_disk_lnum_1;

DESCRIBE c;
```

> c: {node_disk_lnum_1: bytearray}

```
DUMP c;
```

**Expected Result:**

> 36, 136.40000000000001, 187392.0, 13
>
> 36, 105.2, 123084.8, 13

**Throwing the below error**

> 2017-02-06 01:05:49,337 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the
>   script: UNKNOWN 2017-02-06 01:05:49,386 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - Key [pig.schematuple] was not
>   set... will not generate code. 2017-02-06 01:05:49,387 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer -
>   {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, ConstantCalculator,
>   GroupByConstParallelSetter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter,
>   MergeFilter, MergeForEach, PartitionFilterOptimizer,
>   PredicatePushdownOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter,
>   SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter]} 2017-02-06 01:05:49,390 [main]
>   INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.rules.ColumnPruneVisitor - Map
>   key required for a: $0->[node_disk_lnum_1,
>   node_disk_xfers_in_rate_sum, node_disk_bytes_in_rate_22,
>   node_disk_lnum_7]
>
> 2017-02-06 01:05:49,395 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler
>   - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false 2017-02-06 01:05:49,398 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer
>   - MR plan size before optimization: 1 2017-02-06 01:05:49,398 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer
>   - MR plan size after optimization: 1 2017-02-06 01:05:49,425 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRScriptState - Pig
>   script settings are added to the job 2017-02-06 01:05:49,426 [main]
>   INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3 2017-02-06 01:05:49,428 [main] ERROR
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal
>   error. com/twitter/elephantbird/util/HadoopCompat

Please help what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have any nested data in your json,so remove -nestedload

```
a = LOAD '/pig/tc1.log' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader() as (json:map[]);
```