# Loading a json file into PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

How can I load the following json file using PIG?

```
{"age":100,"name":"mkyong.com","messages":["msg 1","msg 2","msg 3"]}
```

I tried something like this but it's giving me exception.

```
jsoncust_table = LOAD 'customers.json' USING JsonLoader('age:int, name:string, messages:chararray');
```

Comment: Can you share the exception? It looks fine.

Comment: It looks like issue with the messages column as its an array, you will have to handle it. I do not think, it can be taken as chararray.

Comment: This is the exception I got. ERROR 1200: <line 1, column 14>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'string'

Comment: Looks like this is the issue with the array only. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26710438/load-json-array-into-pig

Comment: `string` is not a valid datatype in pig. Use `name: chararray`

Comment: yes that's the exact error. Thank you @philantrovert. Can you also suggest me what datatype I should use for "messages":["msg 1","msg 2","msg 3"]?

Answer (score 0):

Pig doesn't have a string datatype. Use chararray instead

[Pig Datatypes](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Data+Types)

```
jsoncust_table = LOAD 'customers.json' USING JsonLoader('age:int, name:chararray, messages:chararray');
```

For loading messages use [elephant-bird jar.](https://github.com/twitter/elephant-bird/blob/master/examples/src/main/pig/nested_json_get_distinct_items_from_nested_array.pig)